# How to remove the last 2 words in a dataframe; Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am filtering my data and I want to remove the year and location (Islamabad, Lahore, etc) in the 'Name' column and I don't know what to do

This is the [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCh8D.png)

Comment: Please include your sample data directly in the question, as _text_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `str.replace` here:

```py
df["Name"] = df["Name"].str.replace(r'\s+\d{4} \w+$', '', regex=True)
```

Comment: I don't know what you did but the data has not changed somehow.

Comment: I did some tweaking and rechecking on the previous line and your code does help. Thanks a lot. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I tried the below and it did the job. Try it and let me know if you faced any problem:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print("Original DataFrame:")
print(df)
def clean_name(name):
    name = re.sub(r'\d{4}', '', name)
    
    name = re.sub(r'\s+[A-Z][a-z]+', '', name)
    
    return name.strip()
df['Name'] = df['Name'].apply(clean_name)
print("\nCleaned DataFrame:")
print(df)
```